# C - malloc for a pointer to struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc

My code works, but i haven't figured out how memory is allocated by malloc to pointer to struct in C. And in my code, i didn't allocate the whole size of my struct to my pointer but only the size of its member, is it good or bad? And if it's bad, what should i do to optimize my code.

Here is my code:

```
struct Student
{
    char name[25];
    float math, physic;
    char rank;
};



void studentManagement(void)
{
struct  Student *s;
int n,i=1;
float ave;

printf("Number of student = ");
scanf("%d", &n);
getchar();

    while(i<=n)
    {
         s = malloc(25*sizeof(char));

         printf("Enter student name: ");
         fgets(s->name,25,stdin);             
         free(s);

         s = malloc(5*sizeof(float));

         printf("Physics grade = ");
         scanf("%f", &s->physic);
         printf("Math grade = ");
         scanf("%f", &s->math);

         getchar();

         ave = ((s->math )+ (s->physic)) / 2;

         if(ave<5) 
             printf("Rank = D\n");
         if(ave >= 5 && ave <= 7) 
             printf("Rank = C\n");
         if(ave >= 7 && ave <= 8) 
             printf("Rank = B\n");
         if(ave > 8) 
             printf("Rank = A\n");

         free(s);
         i++;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `s = malloc(25*sizeof(char));`, you are allocating space and setting `s` to point to this space. `s` is a pointer to `struct Student`. So `s` ought to point to enough space for a `struct Student`. So the proper allocation is:

```
s = malloc(sizeof(struct Student));
```

Another way to do this is to use the size of the thing that `s` points to:

```
s = malloc(sizeof *s);
```

The latter is generally preferred because it remains correct if the code is later changed so that `s` points to a different type of object.

Just after getting the name, you have `free(s);`. This is incorrect. You should only release memory when you are done using it. But you still want to use the object that `s` points to, so it is too early to free `s`.

Similarly, you do not need to use `s = malloc(5*sizeof(float));`. The statement `s = malloc(sizeof *s);` will (if it succeeds) allocate enough memory for **all** of a `struct Student`. You allocate an entire structure, use it, and then free it. You do not allocate pieces of a structure.

Once you have that piece of code working correctly, you should think about why you allocate space for a `struct Student` and then free it soon. If you just want to work with a `struct Student` for one iteration of a loop, you can do it by declaring `struct Student s;` instead of allocating memory and pointing to it. The assignment you are working on may require building an array of `struct Student`, in which case you will have to think about how you allocate memory for an entire array and how many elements you will need in the array.

Comment: But i allocates s = malloc(25*sizeof(char) for the name, so after using it, i thought i should free it so i can continue to allocate s = malloc(5*sizeof(float)) for the grades. And one thing that i still don't understand is: when i have: s = malloc(25*sizeof(char), the pointer points to the allocated memory by malloc (which is 25 * sizeof(char) =25 bytes) not the char name[25] in struct, but how can i still save the inputted name to the member name in struct?

Comment: @ThuanNguyen: I think you have the wrong idea about `malloc` and perhaps about pointers. You do not use `malloc` to allocate memory for parts of a structure. You should not merely allocate 25 bytes, put a name into it, and expect it to be merely associated with the structure that `s` points to. When you declare `struct Student *s;`, there is no structure yet. `s` is merely a pointer that has no value yet. You need to allocate memory for that structure, using `malloc(sizeof *s)`. Then you need to set `s` to point to that memory, with `s = malloc(sizeof *s);`.…

Comment: … Once you do that, `s` is pointing to the structure, which contains `name`, `math`, `physic`, and `rank`. When you use `s->name`, you are using the `name` member inside the structure.

Comment: Thank you for replying me! I understand this now.