# Struct passed from pointer shows wrong values

Tags: c, pointers, memory, struct

I have a variable `struct employee` which I initialized on the heap using `malloc`. I am passing this variable from a pointer using `*tmp` as shown bellow. The problem is that the values of the variable once passed to the function are wrong. I assume this has to do with the pointer but I can't find the mistake. I guess I am forgeting a basic about pointers. To me, I am passing the **variable `struct employee` pointed by `*tmp` (and not its address as passing the pointer would do)**.  Can't see what's wrong in there.
If I check the value inside the `createEmployee()` function or after calling it, they are right, but they are not in `isInformationValid(employee e)`. If I change my code and pass a pointer to the function, everything works all right.

```
typedef struct employee{
  char nom[MAX_NAME_LEN];
  char prenom[MAX_NAME_LEN];
  unsigned short badge;
  unsigned long secret;
  time_t lastAccess;
} employee;

typedef struct maillon maillon;
struct maillon{
  maillon* next;
  maillon* prev;
  employee* e;
};

typedef struct e_list{
  maillon* m;
} e_list;
[...]
int isInformationsValid(employee e){
  int invalidName = (strlen(e.nom) <= 2 || strlen(e.prenom) <= 2); // Problem here
  int invalidBadge = (e.badge < 1000 || e.badge > 9999); // Problem here. e.badge taken as "25789" when I input "1010"
  if(invalidName) { errno = EPERM; perror("Name length must be > 2"); return -1; }
  if(invalidBadge) { errno = EPERM; perror("Badge must be 4 digits"); return -1; }
  return 0;
}

employee* createEmployee(){
  employee* tmp = calloc(1, sizeof(employee*));
  getString("A man needs a last name : ", tmp->nom, MAX_NAME_LEN);
  getString("A man needs a first name : ", tmp->prenom, MAX_NAME_LEN);
  getDigits("Badge (4 digit) : ", &tmp->badge, "%hu");
  getDigits("Secret : ", &tmp->secret, "%lu");
  time_t t = time(NULL);
  tmp->lastAccess = t;
  if(isInformationsValid(*tmp) == -1){ // Passing addr of the struct
    return NULL;
  }
  return tmp;
}
```

What did I miss? Did I do something wrong in any initialization or am I missing a basic thing about pointers ?

## I saw that other questions on stackoverflow has similar questions

The only answers I could reading those other questions was forgotten dynamic allocations on the heap, which is what I think I am doing (maybe the wrong way tho).

## EDIT

I was doing it wrong.

Comment: Take the debugger to inspect the values before the call and in the call.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I can only see it pointing to a random address which doesn't look like having anything stored.

Comment: @CacahueteFrito, that is C.

Comment: See _what_ pointing to a random address?

Comment: @CacahueteFrito I did not import bool.h, doesn't make much difference here. The problem is the value of e.badge which is showing wrong values (showing random int when I am passing "5555" for example)

Comment: @CacahueteFrito This int was intended, thanks for asking.

Comment: Did your `getDigits` correctly read _and store_ the value?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie yes, double checked that, it does correctly reads and store the values.

Comment: You are allocating the size of an `employee *`, but you should be allocating the size of an `employee`

Comment: This line is a major problem and is likely the reason for your trouble: `employee* tmp = calloc(1, sizeof(employee*));`. You're not allocating enough memory to hold `struct employee`, you're allocating enough to hold a *pointer* to it. Depending on your architecture, it's 4, 8 or 2 bytes, likely not enough. Use `calloc(1, sizeof *tmp)` or `callloc(1, sizeof (employee))` to do what you mean.

Comment: @CacahueteFrito Arkadiy Fck. Thanks a LOT for noticing that. Post this as an answer I'll give you my vote !

Comment: @CacahueteFrito, You got it! Would he have written `tmp*` it would have been fine, but `employee*` is indeed only a pointer. Make into an answer to get my upvote.

Comment: No, Nark, don't delete, so @CacahueteFrito can receive his upvote (this little error of yours will be archived for eons...-)

Comment: So I guess all my other `calloc`s are wrong. I'm going to fix that. @Arkadiy CacahueteFrito

Comment: @CacahueteFrito that is because this is a duplicate that I want to delete this post.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C - malloc for a pointer to struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51009229/c-malloc-for-a-pointer-to-struct)

Comment: Don't worry, I don't think you can, anyway.  I've flagged this as a duplicate, so it will be closed soon.

Comment: For the future, you can check the result of `calloc()` with a debugger very easily. E.g., in gdb you can `print sizeof (employee)` Let's say that printed 32. Then you try `print ((char*)tmp)[30]` or `print ((char*)tmp)[31]` - that tell you if the entire length of memory you expect has been filled with 0s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are allocating the size of an `employee *`, but you should be allocating the size of an `employee` (or `*tmp`).